# why am i getting a FloatBuffer is not direct error?

Tags: java, opengl

I am tring to draw an object from an array of vertices. The method for this requires a `FloatBuffer` instead of an array. I make a float buffer from the array but why i run the code i get an error. Btw all of the required attributes are enabled(openGL).

**Code:**

```
float vertices[] ={
        -1, -1, -1,   -1, -1,  1,   -1,  1,  1,   -1,  1, -1,
        1, -1, -1,    1, -1,  1,    1,  1,  1,    1,  1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1,   -1, -1,  1,    1, -1,  1,    1, -1, -1,
        -1,  1, -1,   -1,  1,  1,    1,  1,  1,    1,  1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1,   -1,  1, -1,    1,  1, -1,    1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1,  1,   -1,  1,  1,    1,  1,  1,    1, -1,  1
};

FloatBuffer temp = FloatBuffer.allocate(vertices.length);
temp.put(vertices);
GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, temp);
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FloatBuffer is not direct
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkDirect(BufferChecks.java:139)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertexPointer(GL11.java:2622)
    at XLesson01.render(XLesson01.java:95)
    at XLesson01.run(XLesson01.java:51)
    at XLesson01.main(XLesson01.java:42)
```

**New Code:**

```
ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*8);
    temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer buffer = temp.asFloatBuffer();
    buffer.put(vertices);
    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, buffer);
```

**New Error:**

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x69aa9410, pid=3524, tid=1032

 JRE version: 6.0_22-b04# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [nvoglv32.DLL+0x5a9410]

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 E:\java\workspace4\opengltest\hs_err_pid3524.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct

Comment: Are you obtaining a valid `GL` context?

Comment: Related: http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5665.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously because it is not direct. You can allocate a direct FloatBuffer by creating a ByteBuffer with [allocateDirect](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29) and then getting a FloatBuffer view of it with [asFloatBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asFloatBuffer%28%29).

Comment: but how would i put floats into my bytebuffer?

Comment: With any of the `put` methods. See the [FloatBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/FloatBuffer.html) javadocs.

Comment: tyvm i just allocate the length of my floats times 8 since a float uses 8 bytes. btw for the first time i got a "Fatal runtime error" while experimenting with this lol

Comment: nvm it doesn't work yet. ill put the updated code up top and i get a fatal error when i run it

Comment: I don't know anything about openGL. Maybe you have to reset the FloatBuffer before the call.

Comment: I know this isn't really constructive, but why does the buffer have to be direct?

Answer (score 10):

You could try using `BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(int size)`. `BufferUtils` is part of LWJGL and is designed for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old so I'm impressed it hasn't been mentioned yet. You need to flip() the buffer before using it in glVertexPointer