# Java: FloatBuffer to OpenGL - wrap() vs. allocate() vs. BufferUtils.createBuffer()

Tags: java, opengl, buffer

Datasource:

```
float[] v = { ... };
```

Working example:

```
FloatBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(v.length);
buf.put(v);
buf.flip(); // or buf.rewind()
```

The buffer can now be uploaded to opengl and works fine:

```
...
glBufferData(..., buf, ...);
...
```

Why do the following examples of the buffer creation not also work?

Not working 1:

```
FloatBuffer buf = FloatBuffer.wrap(v);
```

Not working 2:

```
FloatBuffer buf = FloatBuffer.allocate(v.length);
buf.put(v);
buf.flip(); // or buf.rewind()
```

Edit:

After browsing the API code, I found out:

In case of the working example memAddress(buf) returns a valid address, but in the other cases it returns just 0.

Additional infos:

[why am i getting a FloatBuffer is not direct error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637491/why-am-i-getting-a-floatbuffer-is-not-direct-error)

Comment: This might also be platform dependent. I have used `FloatBuffer.wrap()` on Android without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BufferUtils returns a direct buffer whereas the others might not.

You can check the directness of the wrap and allocate methods using isDirect() method. Wrappers are non direct.

Comment: You are right. Take a look to my edit in the question above.

Comment: nice, been a long time since I dabbled in there