# Empty texture when using glTexImage2D with ByteBuffer in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I just got a test texture working in my LWJGL code using an array of `float`s. Now, though, I need to load an image from a file and store it in the texture. I have gotten the image loaded and the data into a `ByteBuffer` object, but when I use `glTexImage2D` like so:

```
GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB,
    4, 4, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

the texture is empty and will render as completely black. I've looked at how other people do this but nothing seems to be helping... The function call is also the same as with the `float` array, except for the *type* parameter, of course. And yes, my image is RGB and yes, it's 4x4. There's probably something *really* simple I'm not getting, so any help is appreciated.

Full working test program:

```
static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!GLFW.glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }

        // Create a window as the GL context
        long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(100, 100, "", NULL, NULL);

        if (window == NULL) {
            GLFW.glfwTerminate();
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        }

        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Generate the texture and set parameters
        int textureID = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);

        // A byte array of 4x4 RBG values
        byte[] data = new byte[] {
                127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0,
                127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0,
                127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0,
                127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0, 127, 127, 0,
        };
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

        // Load the data to the texture
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, 4, 4, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        // glGetError returns 0.

        // Test if the buffer data is correctly stored in the texture.
        // I have unrelated problems while getting the data using a
        // ByteBuffer, so it's a float array for debug purposes.
        float[] floats = new float[data.length];
        GL11.glGetTexImage(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_FLOAT, floats);
        // glGetError returns 0.

        for (float f : floats) {
            System.out.println(f);
        }
        // Expected output is 16 times the following:
        //   0.5
        //   0.5
        //   0.0
        // Actual output: Random (garbage?) values
        // Examples:
        //   0.003921569
        //   0.87843144
        //   1.0
    }
}
```

This reproduced the problem for me. Usual LWJGL libs (lwjgl, opengl and glfw) are needed for this. As mentioned in the code comments, `glGetError` returns zero after each GL call.

Comment: This question is very far away from providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and it is impossible to answer it based on that single GL call alone.

Comment: @derhass I thought it would be clear enough if I told it all worked with the float array as the texture data, and that I have problems changing it to a ByteBuffer... Well, I can post the whole texture gen function if it's needed.

Comment: @derhass I'll try to make a complete, working program of it as well, but that'll have to wait until tomorrow. Also, I haven't asked many questions here before, so I'm definitely not an expert, so excuse me for any stupid things I might do/miss.

Comment: is your image actually 4 by 4 pixels?

Comment: @derhass Edited the question, and added a fully functional test program. Thanks for that tip.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I use OpenGL. glGetError returns 0. And GL11.GL_FLOAT worked when debugging the float array, so it's valid, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
```

the the buffer is not ["direct"](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/nio_buffer_direct.shtml).

You have to use [`BufferUtils.createByteBuffer`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/BufferUtils.html#createByteBuffer(int)):

```
ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(data.length);
buffer.put(data);
buffer.flip();
```

Explanation:

`BufferUtils.createByteBuffer` allocates a direct native-ordered bytebuffer with the specified capacity.

`put(vboData)` transfers the the data to the buffer, beginning at the current position (which is the start of the buffer in this case). The buffer position is incremented by the size of the data. So the new buffer position is at the end of the new data.

`flip()` sets the limit (length) of the buffer to the current position and then the position is set to zero.

Comment: As the linked article says, `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` can be used as well, and I'm guessing it's probably also the "real" way to do it, right?

Comment: @Zakru In [Java: FloatBuffer to OpenGL - wrap() vs. allocate() vs. BufferUtils.createBuffer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974902/java-floatbuffer-to-opengl-wrap-vs-allocate-vs-bufferutils-createbuffer) it is mentioned that it does not work. See also [LWJGL3 Texture](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5559.0)

Comment: Well, it does work for me, but I'll just stick to the `BufferUtils` way, since I think I can trust someone with much more experience.

Comment: @Zark No, I can't find any reason why `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` should not work. There are just some entries in some forums, that makes me unsure. But if it works for you you should use it. The main key is to use a *direct* buffer.

Comment: Found out recently that using `BufferUtils` makes the buffer _native-ordered_. This is assumed by the libraries, and not doing so caused some weird behaviour which I ignored and worked around at the time of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this [wiki](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.3.-Memory-FAQ) and then use "Stack Allocation" or `MemoryUtil` class.

There is actually an even faster method. When you know that you won't never exceed a given quantity per frame, you can allocate it just once, and then use for all your short lived allocations, like that one required by your texture. And then after each frame, you will clear the whole buffer.

I have applied exactly this concept in one of my [project](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/appBuffer)